# Jquery not working Firefox and IE for action executed on link click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cross-browser

I have a page that's functioning well on Chrome, but not on IE or Firefox. I put together this Jsfiddle which shows part of the issue: https://fiddle.jshell.net/dkwsswdw/2/

If you open it on Chrome, you should be able to click on the down arrow at the top of the window and scroll down from div to div. If you open it in Firefox or IE, it stops working.

Any ideas? I understand that there are issues with jQuery not getting called properly in FF and IE, but I'm not sure how it applies to this issue. (I've looked at this extensively and I'm just too new to jQuery to figure out exactly how this applies.)

**Note:**

If it's helpful, here's the actual loop that I'm running in Wordpress to display the posts and add the 'current' class to the first post in the loop:

```
<?php

        // The Arguments
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'strange',
            'posts_per_page' =>-1, 
            'order_by' => 'menu_order'

        );

        $c = 0; 
        $class = ''; 

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <?php

        // If we have the posts...
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <!-- Start the loop the loop --> 
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $c++; 
            if ( $c == 1 ) $class .= ' current'; // if the item is the first item, add class current
            else $class = ''; 
            ?>

                <div id="strange-container" class="strange-container <?php echo $class; ?>">    

                    <img src="<?php the_field('strange-img'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

                    <span><?php the_field('strange-text'); ?></span>

                </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Tried this as well based on what I saw in another thread on Stackoverflow: https://fiddle.jshell.net/dkwsswdw/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, your images are are behind an `htpasswd`.

That said, some browsers like to animate on `body` while others like to animate on `html`.  Change your line that looks like this:

```
$('body').animate({
```

to this:

```
$('html,body').animate({
```

Comment: Thank you! This does resolve it! Is there a resource like caniuse.com that I could reference for browser preferences like this for jQuery? Writing my own script is new to me, and I'd love to be better at finding my own solutions online.

Comment: Not really that I am aware of...it is one of those things that you just pick up with experience.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again. I've been fiddling with this for awhile today, and it proved to be such a simple fix.